# File upload to server using NodeJs and Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I'm trying to upload a file to the server using NodeJs and Multer. But I'm unsuccessful. When I post the file from my front end I get the conditional statement as follow:

```
You must select at least 1 file.
```

The `console.log(req.files)` as per script below returns back an empty array `[]`.

Here below the `userController.js`

```js
   

const mysql = require('mysql');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const upload = require("../middleware/upload");
    
    
exports.update = async (req, res) => {
    message = '';
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var post = req.body;
        var first_name = post.first_name;
        var last_name = post.last_name;


        if (req.files) {
            //    console.log(req.files)


            try {
                await upload(req, res);
                console.log(req.files);

                if (req.files.length <= 0) {
                    return res.send(`You must select at least 1 file.`);
                }

                return res.send(`Files has been uploaded.`);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);

                if (error.code === "LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE") {
                    return res.send("Too many files to upload.");
                }
                return res.send(`Error when trying upload many files: ${error}`);
            }
```

Here my middleware `upload.js`

```js
 
const util = require("util");
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, path.join(`${__dirname}/../../upload`));
  },
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    const match = ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "application/pdf"];

    if (match.indexOf(file.mimetype) === -1) {
      var message = `<strong>${file.originalname}</strong> is invalid. Only accept png/jpeg/pdf.`;
      return callback(message, null);
    }

    var filename = `${Date.now()}-bezkoder-${file.originalname}`;
    callback(null, filename);
  }
});

var uploadFiles = multer({ storage: storage }).array("multi-files", 10);
var uploadFilesMiddleware = util.promisify(uploadFiles);
module.exports = uploadFilesMiddleware;
```

Here my `user.js` for the routing:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');

   router.post('/editcrew/:id',userController.update);
```

And my front end:

```html
<form class="row g-1 needs-validation" method="POST" action="/editcrew/{{this.id}}" encType="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
</form>
<input type="file" name="covid_19D" id="file_box" />

<div class="col-md-1 mt-5 d-grid">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Any advice, suggestion, and direction on the correct path is highly appreciated THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

change the HTML form (add the submit button and other fields inside the form as well):

```
<form class="row g-1 needs-validation" method="POST" action="/editcrew/{{this.id}}" encType="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    <input type="file" name="covid_19D" id="file_box" />
    <div class="col-md-1 mt-5 d-grid">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

add the correct field name in upload.js (the same as file field name specified in the form):

```
var uploadFiles = multer({ storage: storage }).array("covid_19D", 10);
```

in the userController.js, call the upload middleware first, and then check `req.files`, also, move `req.body` variables there as well:

```
const upload = require("./upload");


exports.update = async(req, res) => {

    if (req.method == 'POST') {

        try {

            await upload(req, res);

            var post = req.body;
            var first_name = post.first_name;
            var last_name = post.last_name;

            if (req.files.length <= 0) {
                return res.send(`You must select at least 1 file.`);
            }

            return res.send(`Files has been uploaded.`);

        } catch (error) {

            if (error.code === "LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE") {
                return res.send("Too many files to upload.");
            }
            return res.send(`Error when trying upload many files: ${error}`);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @CherryDT correct, it occurred to me after I posted :)

Comment: Hi there, I modify the script as per above. But no success. The file is linked correctly from the front end to the back end. In the `userController.js`   When I insert   `console.log(req.files)` below `exports.update = async (req, res) => {` it gives me the whole `covid_19D` object from the front end `name` field. When I place `console.log(req.files)` under `await upload(req, res);` the output is still an empty array `[]`. Must be something I'm missing on the upload.js middleware.

Comment: @CesareMannino that sounds like you're already calling upload from somewhere else.. check router

Answer (score 0):

Your file input is outside of the form, so it's not part of what will be sent when the form is submitted.

Move it into the form instead:

```html
<form class="row g-1 needs-validation" method="POST" action="/editcrew/{{this.id}}" encType="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
  <input type="file" name="covid_19D" id="file_box" />
</form>
```

I should mention that most likely the submit button should go into the form tag as well, but since you managed to submit the form nonetheless, I assume you already have some other code in place that handles submission of the form...

Comment: that won't fix it, check my updated answer

Comment: @traynor Are you sure? The OP wrote that they are getting the message "You must select at least 1 file." which comes from inside the `if (req.files)` condition, hence that condition must have been true already, and removing it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: you're right about the form, also, there is an error in the upload middleware, the file name is wrong, it should be `.array("covid_19D", 10);`. the problem is in upload, it uses `util.promisify`, it's not returning right..

Comment: no, it's good, just need call the middleware first, I got lost, as the code is truncated..